# Changing background color of newly opened tab

Tags: javascript

I am opening a file in a new tab using:

`<a  target='_blank' href='/code/some_file.cpp'>`

This does open up the file in a new tab. But I want to change the background color of this newly opened tab. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: it's not allowed to interfere with browser GUI, so you can't do that.

Comment: @Pierre Of course you can. See my answer and link to Fiddle below.

Comment: a TAB is not the background of page ! For me, a TAB is the little rectangle on top of the screen where the browser shows the page title. And this thing can't be styled. So my answer is right if we understand what we are speaking about (tab, not page background)

Comment: @Pierre That's not what the OP was asking about. You took the question too literally. For many people a tab means a window. After all, `window.open()` opens another tab. When the OP said *"This does open up the file in a new tab"*, it was clear he meant `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't open the new window that way as you will have no control over it. Instead, use `window.open()`, which will return a reference to the window so that you can then access it.

The following code does the trick but won't work here in the Stack Overflow Code Snippet environment. You can see it work **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/93seb1ac/)**.

```js
document.getElementById("newWin").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var win = window.open('/code/some_file.cpp');
  
  win.addEventListener("load", function(){
    win.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";  
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="newWin">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan It sure does. This is standard 100 year old code that will work in every browser.  As I said in my answer, it doesn't work in SO (due to security sandboxing), but go to the Fiddle link and you will see it work just fine. You may have a popup blocker preventing the new window from opening.

Comment: Oh right, in incognito it does, but I thought it was about the background of the tab itself, but if it's about the background of the body then it works

Comment: @DimiAnsari Don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer.

Comment: I've changed my code to: `var win = window.open("/code/some_file.cpp");        win.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#333333";`. Still, the background remains white.

Comment: @DimiAnsari Is there CSS in that `.cpp` file that could be overriding the `#333333` instruction? If so, you may have to delay the style until after the page is finished loading.

Comment: @DimiAnsari I've updated the answer to wait until the window is finished loading before attempting to change the color.

Comment: Nope, no CSS in the `.cpp` file, just plain C++ code!

Comment: @DimiAnsari See my updated answer. But, how are you loading a `cpp` file into a browser? The issue may simply be that what you are loading isn't a web page and therefore CSS isn't going to affect it.